# reactjs: how to define componentDidMount inside ES6 const?

Tags: reactjs

I have this react component that is not an ES6 `class`. It's a `const` like :

```
import React from 'react';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';

const Home = (props) => {

    const componentDidMount = () => {
        console.log('component mounted'); // not working
    }


    return <Dashboard />;
}
```

Inside this const how do i define the `componentDidMount` function like i would do in a normal ES6 `class`? this is how i did it before.

```
import React from 'react';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';

class Dashboard extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('component mounted');
    }

    render() {
        return <Dashboard />;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stateless functional components don't support the lifecycle methods.

You can either convert it to a stateful component or wrap it in a stateful container.

Good example of wrapping to get the lifecycle methods:

https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-fetching-data-on-route-change

Comment: i didn't knew that terminology(stateless). thanks, that clears up things

Answer (score 6):

To anyone else learning React and stumbling upon this in the future like me, the accepted answer here is out of date. Please see this question: [componentDidMount equivalent on a React function/Hooks component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53945763/componentdidmount-equivalent-on-a-react-function-hooks-component)

If using React 16.8.0+ you can create the effect of componentDidMount by using the hook `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Your code here
}, []);
```